# Duplicate key value error on Merge

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I get this error on the code below. I don't understand how it can give a duplicate key value error. The key does indeed exist in the database but the code specifies `Merge`. Also, when I first create the entity and save it to the db, all is well, the error occurs only on saves after that. If I add a line to do a `Session.Refresh` before the `Session.Merge` (which restores the entity to the values in the db) the error does not occur. That defeats the point of making any changes, but it shows that it doesn't like changes to `entity`. I've tried playing with different values for `cascade`, but makes no difference. The table has 2 columns `ProjectId` and `FeatureId`, both are Primary Keys. What gives?

It appears the first part of a merge consists of a SQL Delete and the Delete is failing.

> Could not execute batch command.[SQL: SQL not available]
>   Cystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint 'PK_tblProjectFeature'.  Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'dbo.tblProjectFeature'. The duplicate key value is (179,
>   5844). Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tblProjectFeature'. 
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblProjectFeature'. The
>   duplicate key value is (179, 5844).

```
public virtual T Merge (T entity)
{
    using (ITransaction transaction = this.Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            Session.Merge(entity); 
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    return entity;
}
```

hbm.xml

```
<bag name="Projects" table="tblProjectFeature" inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="none">
          <key>
            <column name="FeatureId" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
          </key>
          <many-to-many class="BusinessEntities.Project, Infrastructure.Interface">
            <column name="ProjectId" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
          </many-to-many>
</bag>
```

Comment: What does the mapping look like?

Comment: Added mapping and more info.

Comment: `inverse="true"` is the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the mapping file to `inverse` to true.